# Hibernate is persisting zero instead of double values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.7.RELEASE as application framework, Hibernate as JPA implementation, Spring Data as data access interface, and MySQL 5.7.15 as storage server. I have two models: `Agency` and `ServiceAreaCoverage`. `Agency` has `oneToOne` unidirectional with `ServiceAreaCoverage` at the moment. Here's my application model's and mapping's.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agencies")
public class Agency {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private long phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String websiteUrl;
    private boolean active;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_area_coverage_id")
    private ServiceAreaCoverage serviceAreaCoverage;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "service_area_coverages")
public class ServiceAreaCoverage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitudeSpan;
    private double longitudeSpan;
}
```

I am trying to save `Agency` with `ServiceAreaCoverage` using Spring Data JpaRepository's save method. `Agency` and `ServiceAreaCoverage` both get saved and key constraints are also properly managed. However, `double` values are not getting saved. Instead of double values, zero is getting saved. I cannot think of any reason for this result to happen nor I can think of troubleshooting idea's. So any help would really be appreciated guys. Here's my some other codes and references relative to this matter.

Service Code:

```
@Service
public class AgencyServiceImpl implements AgencyService {

    @Autowired
    private AgencyRepository agencyRepository;

    @Override
    public void createAgency(Agency agency) {

    this.agencyRepository.save(agency);
    }
}
```

Repository Interface Code:

```
@Repository
public interface AgencyRepository extends JpaRepository<Agency, String> {

}
```

Generated Table Details:
Agencies Table:
[image]

ServiceAreaCoverage Table:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your database tables?

Comment: Hello @Beethoven, I have added screenshot of generated table structures. Thank you looking at this matter.

Comment: Hm, can't see yet, what could be going wrong. Just a few general troubleshooting ideas: 1. Are the fields named differently from the corresponding database columns, e.g. `latitudeSpan`/`latitude_span` mapped correctly, somewhere? 2. One important place to look at is, of course, where the values of the double fields are set. 3. It is often useful to set the logger 'org.hibernate.SQL' to debug to see the SQL queries generated by Hibernate.

Comment: Which database are you using? please share a screenshot of zeroed double data stored in db.

Comment: @Beethoven:
1. Yes. Fields names are different from database. I used hibernate default naming strategy: ImprovedNamingStrategy which maps model field names with additional underscore separating words. For example: In case of latitudeSpan, hibernate maps this field with latitude_span column. I am basically auto generating database schema too.

2. Yes I have been checking values and I am getting fine values in service layer before persisting Agency entity.

Comment: 3. Enabling org.hibernate.SQL at DEBUG level, entity is getting listed with zero as field values as well.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad:

I am using MySQL 5.7.15.

Comment: You mean any double value(10.52) is stored as 0. or 0.0 is stored as 0? If the first one then please share the entire code used to save the double value. Also, elaborate the code written for Agency & ServiceAreaCoverage  classes. I want to see the getters/ setters of that classes.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad: It's the first case. I have almost included the entire code in question and yes I do have getters and setters for all of model fields. Also code so save is just a one line code in service implementation because of using Spring data.

Comment: before saving the agency object (in service createAgency method of AgencyServiceImpl) in db try to print the values of it on console and check whether the double is correct?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad: I have already tried it and before persisting Agency object,  I am getting value correctly. I am guessing it has something to do with hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.

You should use wrapper classes instead of primitives. 
Please change double to **Double** in your ServiceAreaCoverage class as it can hold even null value. Make sure the getter/setters are in Double instead of double.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_area_coverages")
public class ServiceAreaCoverage {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;
 private Double latitude;
 private Double longitude;
 private Double latitudeSpan;
 private Double longitudeSpan;
}
```

**Note:** You can not use the primitive double when the DB column is set as **not-null="true"**.
                                                                               Always use wrapper classes, so you don't have to think for 0 or null.

Comment: Sorry for delaying, I was quite busy. Unfortunately, this didn't work too. However after this change, I started getting NPE. And I noticed that, if i changed cascade to merge, then hibernate successfully persist the ServiceAreaCoverage too. Looking at logs, in PERSIST case hibernate first inserts agency object and then do other cascading task. In MERGE case, hibernate is first inserting ServiceAreaCoverage object before inserting agency object. I am still looking in detail how these two cascading operation works. I will notify you when things gets clearer. Thanks